# Consequences of Singletons

Tags: iphone, singleton, application-singleton

So I just delved into the Singleton classes and yes, I find them quite helpful. I use my singletons mostly for data storage for multiple targets (views, tables etc.). That being said, I can already see myself going to implement a lot of singletons in my project.

But can a lot of singletons have a negative impact? From what I've read about singletons is that you create one instance for each of them in a proces. Other class instances get released (assuming they get released properly) from memory, then should singletons be released too?

So to narrow it down to one question: Is it harmful to have a lot of singletons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singletons don't scale.  No matter what you *think* should be a singleton, when your system gets bigger, it turns out you needed more than one.

If you NEVER need more than one, a singleton is fine.  However, as systems scale, you typically need more than one of *anything* within its own context.

Singletons are merely another way to say "global".  It's not bad, but generally, it's not a good idea for systems that evolve and grow in complexity.

Comment: Hm, I see your point. Made me answer my own question too, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

From GOF Book:

> The Singleton pattern has several benefits:
>
> 1. Controlled access to sole instance. Because the Singleton class encapsulates its sole instance, it can have strict control over how
>      and when clients access it.
> 2. Reduced name space. The Singleton pattern is an improvement over global variables. It avoids polluting the name space with global
>      variables that store sole instances.
> 3. Permits refinement of operations and representation. The Singleton class may be subclassed, and it's easy to configure an application
>      with an instance of this extended class. You can configure the
>      application with an instance of the class you need at run-time.
> 4. Permits a variable number of instances. The pattern makes it easy to change your mind and allow more than one instance of the Singleton
>      class. Moreover, you can use the same approach to control the number
>      of instances that the application uses. Only the operation that grants
>      access to the Singleton instance needs to change.
> 5. More flexible than class operations. Another way to package a singleton's functionality is to useThe Singleton class can be
>      subclassed. class operations (that is, static member functions in C++
>      or class methods in Smalltalk). But both of these language techniques
>      make it hard to change a design to allow more than one instance
>      ofclass. Moreover, static member functions in C++ are never virtual,
>      so subclasses can't override them polymorphically.